For all polynomials $g$ there exists a polynomial $f$ with $g = \Delta f$
I want to show that, given any polynomial $g: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, I can construct another polynomial $f$ with the property that $g = \Delta f$, where $\Delta f(n) = f(n+1) - f(n)$.
What I know / what I've tried:

If $\deg(f) = d$, then $\deg(\Delta f) = d-1$, this can be easily shown: $\Delta(n^k) = -n^k + (n+1)^k = -kn^{k-1} + \text{lower terms}.$

Letting $f(n) = a_0 + a_1n + a_2n^2 + a_3n^3 + \dots + a_dn^d$, we have
\begin{align}
f(n+1) - f(n) &= a_1 + a_2((n+1)^2-n^2) + a_3((n+1)^3-n^3) + \dots + a_d((n+1)^d-n^d).
\end{align}
I've tried putting $g(n) = f(n+1) - f(n)$ and seeing if I can gage something about what $g$ has to look like in relation to $f$ but I've hit a dead-end.
It should be important to mention that this is an exercise found very early in an analysis book (Deitmar) and as such I wouldn't expect it to make use of any advanced methods, especially when comparing it to other problems on the same page (which are very simple). So maybe it's simply asking to show that $f$ is a polynomial without constructing it (maybe with induction?) but I genuinely don't know, and haven't found any info on it online.

Hint:  Think of $\Delta$ as  a linear map between vector spaces (it takes polynomials of degree $≤n$ to polynomials of degree $<n$).  What's the kernel?

Alternatively:  Just "integrate".  Of course, the discrete version of the integral here is just the sum.

I wonder if this can be proven inductively in a straightforward fashion

@MPW Yes, the answer by Yves Daoust would be easy to recast as a proof by induction (or a construction of the partial inverse by recursion).

One way to do this is to use the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula.
Another way is to note that, for example, for degree $3$ polynomials, we can write
$$
\Delta\begin{bmatrix}x\\x^2\\x^3\\x^4\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\1&2&0&0\\1&3&3&0\\1&4&6&4\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x^2\\x^3\end{bmatrix}\tag1
$$
Inverting the matrix in $(1)$, we get
$$
\Delta\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\-\frac12&\frac12&0&0\\\frac16&-\frac12&\frac13&0\\0&\frac14&-\frac12&\frac14\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\x^2\\x^3\\x^4\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x^2\\x^3\end{bmatrix}\tag2
$$
Using $(2)$, we can find a degree $4$ polynomial $f$ for any degree $3$ polynomial $g$ so that
$$
\Delta f=g\tag3
$$
It is fairly simple to see how to extend this for higher degree polynomials.

The square matrix looks like the same matrix that appears at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Modern_period (but of order $4$ rather than $5$). Is that a coincidence? It is essentially Pascal's triangle without the $1$ at the end of each row.

@GeoffreyTrang: it is not a coincidence. Faulhaber's Formula can be derived by an application of the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to polynomials.

On the high level, this is really just inverting a triangular matrix, so I think robjohn's answer is preferred. However, since you've mentioned this is an early exercise, here's how you can write the proof without directly referring to that structure.
We prove by induction on $d$ the following statement:

For every polynomial $g$ of degree at most $d$, there exists $f$ such that $g=\Delta f$.

For $d=0$, if $g(n)=c$ then clearly $f(n)=cn$ works.
Otherwise, let $g(n) = an^d + h(n)$ where $h$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d-1$. As you've noticed, $\Delta (an^{d+1}) = (d+1)an^d + i(n)$ where $i$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d-1$.
Therefore $g(n)-\frac{1}{d+1} \Delta (an^{d+1})$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d-1$. By the induction hypothesis, there is a $j(n)$ such that $g(n)-\frac{1}{d+1} \Delta (an^{d+1}) = \Delta j(n)$ and because $\Delta$ linear, $g(n) = \Delta (\frac{1}{d+1} an^{d+1} + j(n))$. QED.
As an exercise, you can use this proof to write $x^3$ as $\Delta f(n)$.
